# GrantAspNetServiceAccountAccessAction failed when install CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

When I install MSCRM 2015, I have met the problem

Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantAspNetServiceAccountAccessAction failed 
"The parameter is incorrect"

[Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantAspNetServiceAccountAccessAction failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm3Al.jpg)


Our team has used the solution mentioned in [Unable to install crm 2013 on server 2012](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1fc14182-3dd5-4077-a467-06d55bbc885e/unable-to-install-crm-2013-on-server-2012?forum=winservergen), and the installed is performed by domain administrator account, but still the above problem exists.

We have checked the OU, there are no "Account Unknown" entries in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, We managed to solve the problem. The cause is due to the customer’s AD version. The customer has 4 AD servers. 
One of the AD servers is on Window 2008 which we thought fulfill the AD requirement for MSCRM2015. However, the functional levels of the AD is actually window 2003 as it takes the lowest function level version from other AD servers even it has the higher version. The pre-requisite for MSCRM2015 is that AD is window 2008 and above therefore it gives the error.